# Why was the ampersand chosen as the symbol for references in C++?

Tags: c++, c, reference, history

Does anyone have an idea why the ampersand was chosen as the way to denote references in C++?

AFAIK (though I don't have the book near me), Stroustroup didn't explain that choice, which I find a little odd because the same symbol was already used for address-of in C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stroustrup was always very reluctant to introduce a new reserved symbol or name, so he probably used it to avoid making the feature look weird to users of C.

Comment: That makes sense. Though IMHO, the whole concept of references was bizarre enough for long-time C users, that having to suddenly have the address-of operator have a different semantics may not have been natural...

Comment: Hmm... maybe you shouldn't look at this: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1690.html

Comment: I just remembered something from D&EC++ - he wishes now he'd put in an 'abstract' keyword instead of using '= 0' on virtual methods; but the reaction to new reserved words was violently negative (though - ironically - surely it wouldn't have needed to been a reserved word?)

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Earwicker's response which I generally agree with. I would also speculate that since & is the "address-of" operator, it is somewhat fitting. Since a reference in many ways is like passing by **address** instead of by **value**.

In addition to that, taking the address of a variable is often referred to as "referencing"

(Yes I know that references don't *have* to be implemented using pointers under the hood, I am referring to the way they conceptually work).

This is just speculation though.

Answer (score 2):

Who knows why Stroustrup does anything, but my guess is that because the *implementation* of reference parameters involves passing the address of an lvalue, Stroustrup chose the C address-of operator because it would give C programmers the right idea about the cost model.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my theory on that. I think it has much to do with what operators are valid (syntactically) for symbols. Consider

```
int a[1]; // a[1] is valid (syntactically)
int *a; // *a is valid
int a(char, bool); // a(<a char>, <a bool>) is valid (function call)
int C::*a; // <a C>.*a is valid
```

Conceptually, in those declarations what is named with a type (`C`, `char`, `bool`) is substituted with an expression of that type later on. Of course the intention is to reuse as much of the existing language as possible. So i think he used `&`:

```
int &a; // &a is valid
```

The important one is that `&` is *only* valid on the kind of expression a reference denotes: For `lvalues`. References are lvalues (named variables are too) and only for them `&` can be applied:

```
int &g(); // &g() is valid (taking the address of the referred to integer)
int g(); // &g() is *not* valid (can't apply to temporary int)
```

Comment: I vote up, but notice that "int &a; // &a is valid" is not allowed without assignation...

Comment: yes i'm aware of that. I intentionally left it uninitialized because i thought it would not make it clearer to insert an initialization = some_int; likewise when i would have defined an empty class C for the member pointer case. i wanted to highlight their use in expressions. thanks for your +1 :)

Comment: sadly, all this breaks with rvalue references in C++1x where it looks like int &&a; :)

Answer (score 2):

My thought was that there are 2 symbols used in pointers: * and &.
since int* means a pointer to an int, probably Stroustrup didn't want to introduce a whole new symbol. Since references are sort of like pointers, he stuck with &. Plus, the only previously valid use of & was to take the address of something, so it was OK to use in declarations.