# C++ Reference Variable Declaration Syntax Reasoning

Tags: c++, syntax, reference

All other declaration syntaxes in C++ make a lot of sense, for examples:

```
int i;
```

`i` is an `int`

```
int *i;
```

when `i` is dereferenced, the result is an `int`

```
int i[];
```

when `i` is subscripted, the result is and `int`

```
int *i[];
```

when `i` is subscriped, then the result is derefrenced, the final result is an `int`

But when you look at the syntax for reference variables, this otherwise consistent reasoning falls apart.

```
int &i = x;
```

“when the address of `i` is taken, the result is an `int`” makes no sense.

Am I missing something, or is this truly an exception to the apparent reasoning behind the other sytaxes? If it is an exception, why was this syntax chosen?

Edit:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670154) addresses why the `&` symbol may have been chosen for this purpose, but not whether or not there is a universally consistent way to read declarations different from the way described above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was the ampersand chosen as the symbol for references in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670154/why-was-the-ampersand-chosen-as-the-symbol-for-references-in-c)

Comment: Additionally, even the function pointer declaration syntax is consistent with the rest. `int (*i)(long)`, when `i` is derefrenced, and the result is called with a `long` as a parameter, the final result is an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

Once bound, a reference becomes an alias for its referent, and cannot be distinguished from it (except by `decltype`). Since `int&` is used exactly as `int` is, a declaration-follows-usage syntax could not work for declaring references.

The syntax for declaring references is pretty straightforward, still. Just write down a declaration for the corresponding pointer type, then replace the `*` used for the initial dereference by `&` or `&&`.

Comment: you say declaration-follows-usage syntax is impossible for references, but I believe `int *&i` would have worked. Currently it means "`i` has type reference to a pointer to an int", but if things had gone differently, it may have been able to mean "If the address of `i` were taken, and then the result were derefrenced, the final result would be an `int`". To me, this seems like it would be more consistent. Admittedly, it may seem clunkier to some, but if that is really the issue, why not use a new symbol?